# Problem with DataRange and PlotRange in ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the following ArrayPlot:

```
M = RandomReal[1, {5, 9}];

ArrayPlot[M, FrameTicks -> Automatic, DataRange -> {{11, 19}, {1, 5}},
  AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Now, I wanted to use PlotRange to plot only the columns 12 to 18, so I tried this:

```
ArrayPlot[M, FrameTicks -> Automatic, DataRange -> {{11, 19}, {1, 5}},
  AspectRatio -> 1/2, PlotRange -> {{12, 18}, All}]
```

[image]

But when I do this, a part of the plot is cut off because the numbers in PlotRange are not interpreted as the orders of the columns. Is there a way that I can select the orders of the columns I want to be ploted ?

Is there a way, for example, that the orders of the columns are given by a list, like, in this case, x={11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}, and I can use this to select just 12 to 18? That would be great.

Comment: `PlotRange -> {{11.5, 18.5}, All}` or `PlotRange -> {{11.5, 18.5}, {0.5, 5.5}}`?

Comment: Yeah I guess this works for plotting this particular exemple but I really wanted to be able to select the rows I need to plot by the numbers I give to the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom@2
M = RandomReal[1, {5, 9}];
{r, c} = Dimensions@M;
xTicks = Transpose@{Range@c, 10 + Range@c};
yTicks = Transpose@{Range@r, 0 + Range@r};
ArrayPlot[M, FrameTicks -> {{yTicks, yTicks}, {xTicks, xTicks}}, 
 DataReversed -> True]
```

[image]

```
m2 = M[[All, 2 ;; 8]];
{r, c} = Dimensions@m2;
xTicks = Transpose@{Range@c, 11 + Range@c};
yTicks = Transpose@{Range@r, 0 + Range@r};
ArrayPlot[m2, FrameTicks -> {{yTicks, yTicks}, {xTicks, xTicks}}, 
 DataReversed -> True]
```

[image]

```
m2 = M[[2 ;; 4, 2 ;; 8]];
{r, c} = Dimensions@m2;
ticks[xStart_, yStart_] := {Transpose@{Range@r, yStart + Range@r - 1},
   Transpose@{Range@c, xStart + Range@c - 1}}
ArrayPlot[m2, FrameTicks -> Transpose@{ticks[12, 6], ticks[12, 6]}, 
 DataReversed -> True]
```

[image]