# Changing Labels in Matrix Plot, DataRange flips Y labels?

Tags: graphics, matrix

I have a matrix, with "natural" indexes of 0-8.

I'm using MatrixPlot to display my matrix.  However, I'd like to fix the tick labels, to run from 0-8 instead of Mathematica's default of 1-9.  I thought DataRange was the tool to do that.  But DataRange clearly fails, as you can see below.  In reading the docs for ArrayPlot, I'm not seeing any other means for accomplishing this task.  I'm sure I'm missing something stupid here.

```
totals = Table[(2 a - b)^2, {a, 0, 8}, {b, 0, 8}];
MatrixPlot[totals, FrameLabel -> "Default, 1 based labelling"]
MatrixPlot[totals, DataRange -> {{0, 8}, {0, 8}},  FrameLabel -> "Attempt to improve labelling to be zero based."]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241060/problem-with-datarange-and-plotrange-in-arrayplot/241068#241068)   here.

```
 m = totals = Table[(2 a - b)^2, {a, 0, 8}, {b, 0, 8}];
    {r, c} = Dimensions@m;
    ticks[xStart_, yStart_] := {Transpose@{Range@r, yStart + Range@r - 1},
       Transpose@{Range@c, xStart + Range@c - 1}}
    MatrixPlot[m, FrameTicks -> Transpose@{ticks[0, 0], ticks[0, 0]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I simpler way is to use the `FrameTick` option pof `MatrixPlot`: `FrameTicks ->Table[i, {4}, {i, 0, 8}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber That doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Add the option `DataReversed -> True` ***and*** `Reverse` the input matrix:

```
MatrixPlot[Reverse@totals, DataReversed -> True,
 DataRange -> {{0, 8}, {0, 8}}, 
 FrameLabel -> "Attempt to improve labelling to be zero based."]
```

[image]

Comment: your answer gets at a point of confusion for me.  I know that image coordinates have the origin in the upper left hand corner, and graphics objects have the origin in the lower left hand corner.  It appears that DataRange works in graphics coordinate space?  Can you explain more of what's going on here?  Why do you have to do these reverses to get data range to work?

Comment: @John, I too am often puzzled  re how `DataRange` works. The documentation page [DataRange >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html)  says _**"For ArrayPlot, the settings for DataRange refer to the coordinates of the centers of each cell."**_  (that is, _**not**_ to the  row and column indices of each cell as is the case when the option `DataRange` is not used.) Adding the option `DataReversed  -> True`  gets us the desired  labeling of  vertical ticks,...

Comment: ...  but it reverses the  order of rows so the picture is flipped.  `Reverse`ing the input matrix _undoes_ the flippping done by the option `DataReversed ->True`.

Answer (score 0):

as you do not believe that `FrameTicks` works:

```
ft1 = Table[i, {i, 0, 8}];
ft2 = Table[{i, 8 - i}, {i, 0, 8}];
totals = Table[(2 a - b)^2, {a, 0, 8}, {b, 0, 8}];
MatrixPlot[totals, DataRange -> {{0, 8}, {0, 8}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {ft2, ft1, ft2, ft1}, 
 FrameLabel -> "Attempt to improve labelling to be zero based."]
```

[image]

Comment: The Y axis is wrong in your chart.  Compare your Y axis labels to mine, and you'll see that they are reversed.

Comment: I changed this.

Comment: It's interesting, that you're having the same issues as @klgr.  It's helpful to see masters struggle with this as well....  i.e. it is in fact non-intuitive, as opposed to me missing something.